# How to write the below in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to write the big C in the picture below, Could anyone tell me how to write it?. And what is the name of this kind of letters?

[image: C letter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `amsfonts` package, you can use the so-called blackboard bold font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\[
    \mathbb{C}
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]